# jQuery - Slick carousel - How to use appendTo() in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, carousel, slick.js

I’m using [Slick carousel](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) jQuery plugin. In the [docs](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/README.markdown) it has an option `appendArrows`. As I understand it can be used to make the arrows stick to a different element. I use a carousel that is nested so that each slide has a title, link, description and than a couple sub-slides that are pictures. With the default settings the nav arrows are centred to the whole slide. I’d like them to be appended only to the pictures but I can’t figure out how to do it. `appendArrows: $('img’)` does not work.

Here’s the markup:

```
<div class="slider-for">

            <div class="single-item">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <a href=“#” target="_blank">example.com</a>
                <p>Description.</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            </div>

            <div class="single-item">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <a href=“#” target="_blank">example.com</a>
                <p>Description.</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            </div>

    <div class="single-item">
                <h4>Title</h4>
                <a href=“#” target="_blank">example.com</a>
                <p>Description.</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            </div>

</div>
```

And JS:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        swipe: false,
        accessibility: false,
        arrows: false,
    });

 $('.single-item').slick({
        slide: 'img',
        dots: true,
        speed: 500,
        arrows: true,
        appendArrows: $('img'),
    });`
```

EDIT: I think the question was not clear, my bad. The `.slider-for` is toggled by a `.slider-nav` that I omitted from the example. It all works, my problem is more one of aesthetics. When the arrows are appended to the whole `.single-item`they are centred vertically to the height of the whole `<div class="single-item">` and that looks odd since only the `<img>`s inside it are actually sliding. I'd like to append the arrows to the `<img>`'s so that they will be centred vertically to the height of the image. I hope that makes more sense.

I guess what I'm asking really is: how do I target the `<img>`'s inside `<div class="single-item">` with `appendArrows()`? The docs state:

> Option: appendArrows; Type: string; Default: $(element); Desc.: Change
>   where the navigation arrows are attached (Selector, htmlString, Array,
>   Element, jQuery object)

How do I use that? Please bear in mind that I'm a total beginner, I don't know much JS, so I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: appendArrows probably accepts only a unique container element i.e. an element ID. Can you post a jsfiddle?

Comment: So should I add e.g. `#slide` to the `<img>`'s, and then `appendArrows: $('#slide')`? I can't make a jsfiddle since I'm not at home right now.

Comment: No. ID's must be unique on a page. Also, you should not be trying to attach the arrows to every image element. The appendArrows function exists to append the left/right arrows to a single DOM element only. You should be appending them to the .slider-for element.

Comment: Of course you're right about the ID's. Noob error. ;) As I said in one of the comments under Gregory's answer, I want the arrows to toggle the `<img>`'s inside `.single-item`, the `.slider-for` is taken care of by `.slider-nav` that I omitted in the example code. I quess my question was not clear, should have provided the whole code. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. It was a silly mistake. I just moved the `<div class="single-item">` down, to wrap only the `<img>`'s and wrapped the whole thing in another `div`. Like this:

```
    <div>
            <h4>Title</h4>
            <a href=“#” target="_blank">example.com</a>
            <p>Description.</p>
        <div  class="single-item">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/960x540">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding the following CSS:

```
.slick-prev
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}
.slick-next
{
    position: absolute;
    right: 50px;
}
```

and amend the JS to reflect the following:

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        fade: true,
        swipe: false,
        accessibility: false,
        arrows: true
    });
    $('.single-item').slick({
        slide: 'img',
        dots: true,
        speed: 500,
        arrows: false
    });
```

If the above produces your desired output, you can tweak the position of the next arrow by adjusting the *right* property of .slick-next

Comment: But that way the arrows would toggle the `.slider-for` instead of `.single-item > img`, wouldn't they?

Comment: Yes they would. I must have understood incorrectly then. Would you like the arrows to behave as the dots would i.e the arrows go to the next image in that single-item? In this case, what would toggle the slider-for?

Comment: Yes. The `.slider-for` is toggled via `.slider-nav` that I omitted from the above code as I didn't think that could be the problem. It is basically a synced slider like the example on [Slick page](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) with a `.single-item` added inside.